# How to configure a custom source to feed Spring Boot's @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm new to Spring Boot and reading about how @ConfigurationProperties annotation enables auto-injection of field values without @Value annotation.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(locations = "classpath:some.properties", prefix = "something")
public class MyConfiguration { .. }
```

I'd like to use Groovy's `ConfigSlurper` to read my property configuration. Is there a way to associate `@ConfigurationProperties` with a custom property reader, may be a custom extension of Spring class that deals with `ConfigSlurper`? Or is there a way to simulate the same behavior with a different feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not what `@ConfigurationProperties` is meant to do. `@ConfigurationProperties` binds whatever is available from the `Environment`. The `locations` attribute is deprecated in 1.4 and will be removed in a future release.

The idea is that you specify a prefix and if they are keys matching that prefix in the environment, we inject the relevant properties in your POJO.If you want to use that infrastructure with this mechanism, please remove the `locations` attribute on the annotation and update the environment with your own property source. The other answer gives you a way to do that and you can use an `EnvironmentPostProcessor` to hook your implementation to the environment.

Comment: Thanks very much @Stéphane Nicoll. Now I finally understand that `Environment` is the link between actual configuration values and @ConfigurationProperties. Btw, I created a custom `EnvironmentPostProcessor`. The bean was getting created but its  `postProcessEnvironment(..)` was not being invoked. I'm not sure how I could hook my implementation to the environment using it.

Comment: The `Environment` is created before the application context starts so registering it as a bean as no effect. The doc does not help so I've created [#6010](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6101). See [this example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories#L29-L32)

Comment: Thanks for your time. Adding `MyEnvironmentPostProcessor` to spring.factories did the trick. Just wondering if I could just add `MyEnvironmentPostProcessor` to `spring.factories` or do I still need to carry over other entries like `SpringApplicationJsonEnvironmentPostProcessor`, etc? I wonder if my entry in spring.factories gets appended to already defined `org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor` entries in some other META-INF

Comment: your entry is an additional entry, you don't need to bother with others that will be invoked as well transparently.

Answer (score 4):

You can do so by implementing your own [`PropertySourceLoader`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/env/PropertySourceLoader.html):

```
public class ConfigSlurperPropertySourceLoader implements PropertySourceLoader {

    @Override
    public String[] getFileExtensions() {
        return new String[] { "groovy" };
    }

    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> load(String name, Resource resource, String profile) throws IOException {
        ConfigObject source = new ConfigSlurper(profile).parse(resource.getURL());
        return new ConfigObjectPropertySource(name, source);
    }
}
```

Extending [`PropertySource<T>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html) to read values from `ConfigObject` (the `ConfigObjectPropertySource` above). Then you register it inside [`META-INF/spring.factories`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html#boot-features-locating-auto-configuration-candidates):

```
# PropertySource Loaders
org.springframework.boot.env.PropertySourceLoader=\
org.example.ConfigSlurperPropertySourceLoader,\
org.springframework.boot.env.PropertiesPropertySourceLoader,\
org.springframework.boot.env.YamlPropertySourceLoader
```

The `spring-groovy-config` already implements it and is available [on github](https://github.com/davidiamyou/spring-groovy-config).

Comment: Thanks, sorry if I missed a detail but how can I link `@ConfigurationProperties` with my custom `ConfigSlurperPropertySourceLoader` ?

Comment: Looks like the answer by @Stéphane Nicoll describes how to link them.

Comment: Thanks for response.  Accepted the other answer as it addressed how the `@ConfigurationProperties` works, via Environment. Anyways, above should help me with Groovy related implementation details.